# Why the LEFT OUTER JOIN performace is bad on SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-ce

hi i tried a select query that contains an left outer join on  SQL Server CE and its taking like 30 seconds to execute.
and then i changed the same query to be an inner join and its taking less then 1 second.
the same outer query is very fast on SQL server 2008.
does anyone knows why is that?
also what is the fix for this performance problem?
i am thinking of 2 queries that i union but i don't like this solution really cause of code repetition.
thanks

Edit:
another query that have bad performance is `select * from table where item not in (select item from table2)`
very strange really but this query need to be changed to left outer join so the performance is fixed

Comment: How many rows are there in the left-hand-side table of your LEFT JOIN?

Comment: What is the query, schema etc please?

Comment: there is 3600 rows in 1 table and 6400 in the other

Comment: well it apears that this problem is general and not specifique to my query and schema.  anyway i found a fix , so thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem
It Appears that SQL server CE have problem with optimizing  outer joins.
So the problem occurs where is there is an index in one table and no index in other one.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984(SQL.100).aspx
the part "Limit Using Outer JOINs"
The fix was to add an index on the foreign key and the performance was fixed

Comment: i cant approve my own answer until 2 days are elapsed :( "You can accept your own answer in 2 days (click on this box to dismiss)"